# Xamarin Studio (V6.2.0.1829) is only running in the background

Tags: xamarin

I have tried all the ways to install Xamarin Studio on my Windows 10 pro laptop with VS2015 installed. My Xamarin for VS2015 is working. I would like to try Xamarin Studio for some apps. I have downloaded the Xamarin Studio for Windows (6.2.0.1829, the newest). After a successful installation (resolved many issues related to prerequisites), the Xamarin Studio would only run in background. Since I started it many times, there were no Xamarin interface, I checked the process manager and found each time it was running in background). I have searched solutions for 1 day, and evaluated all suggestions, including re-install, repair, reloading, restart. I still could not fix the problem. Please help me to make it run in foreground.

Comment: there is no Xamarin Studio for Windows anymore. Just the opt-on/add-on Xamarin for Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

try to update gtk to  2.12.26 .this works for me